# How to call update on component, only when poll is finish in Primefaces. From the View

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The update="" is being called on each interval. Is there a way to call an update only when the poll is stopped, and only once?

Eksample: How do I update **button-fragment** only once, when the poll stops?

```
<p:poll interval="2" update="@(.button-fragment)" stop="#{stopMethod()}">
```

Edit: I would like to do it from the view

Comment: Then do the same but in javascript... but sinve you need to inform the server, you need a remote command. Or... override the poll 'stop'  javascript implementation to do a final poll

Comment: Its no way to do it with the Primefaces components alone?

Comment: Yes, javascript and remote command... But not with just the poll. Since it is a very, very uncommon usecase and components just have the functionality that is regularly used. You are the first to request this

Comment: To proceed further: Whether or not you find a solution to your problem, registering a feature request for Primefaces to add a "onfinished" or "onstopped" listener for `p:poll` seems like a valid request for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the fact that your poll never stops, I would do something similar to

```
<p:poll interval="2" stop="isPollStopped()" listener="updateOnPollStop()">
```

and in the view bean

```
public boolean isPollStopped() {
    return ...;
}

public void updateOnPollStop() {
    final boolean pollStopped = this.isPollStopped();

    if (pollStopped) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("@(.button-fragment)");
    }
}
```

Edit:

Totally not tested, but perhaps this might work:

```
<p:poll interval="2" oncomplete="handlePollComplete(xhr, status, args)" stop="#{stopMethod()}">

function handlePollComplete(xhr, status, args) {
    if (!PF(<YOUR_POLL_ID>).active) {
        PF(<YOUR_UPDATEE_ID>).update()
    }
}
```

Edit 2 (using `remoteCommand`)

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateOnPollStop" update="@(.button-fragment)"/>
<p:poll widgetVar="myPoll" interval="2" oncomplete="handlePollComplete(xhr, status, args)" stop="#{stopMethod()}">

function handlePollComplete(xhr, status, args) {
    if (!PF('myPoll').active) {
        updateOnPollStop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I would like to do it all from the view, if its possible. I updated the description

Comment: Oh? Never new about `PF('@(.button-fragment)').update()` Have to try that soon. Great feature!

Comment: @Kukeltje not sure about my first shot of referencing the widget to update so I edited my answer,

Comment: Note that PF takes a widgetVar, not a clientId

Comment: Are you sure you don't need https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/ajax/javascriptApi for updating components? I cannot find the update function in the widget JS code.